# How do I automatically re-load a file that gets modified by a bang (!) commandin Vim?

Tags: vim, jslint

I have set up a line of vimscript in my `.vimrc` file to pretty print JavaScript files:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :!js-beautify -r -j %<cr>
```

I want to just automatically reload the file instead of being prompted when vim comes back from the shell, is that possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:!` can be used a) to execute arbitrary shell commands *or* b) as a filter.

You are using it to run `js-beautify` against the file associated with the current buffer with the following consequences:

- You are forced to exit Vim.
- The file is modified outside of Vim so you get a prompt asking you if you want to reload or not.

Hence the many seemingly pointless `<CR>`.

What you actually want is to run `js-beautify` *as a filter* against the current buffer, which doesn't require you to exit Vim or press `<CR>`:

```
nnoremap <leader>p :%!js-beautify -f - -j<cr>
```

- the special range `%` represents the whole buffer, it's the range on which we want to apply our filter
- `-f -` passes the content of the buffer via `stdin`

That's it: no `<CR>`, no prompt, no mess.

As a bonus, here is a custom command from my config (I didn't want a mapping for that):

```
command! -buffer -range=% Format execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!js-beautify -f - -j -B -s " . &shiftwidth
```

***edit***

You can use context marks to return the cursor to its initial position:

```
nnoremap <leader>p m`:%!js-beautify -f - -j<CR>``
```

Comment: Rockin'!  This works well for me.  Know of any way to keep the cursor in the same "neighborhood" as it was before, instead of jumping to the top of the buffer?

Comment: Much better thought out than my own take. I will attribute my own lack of such Insightfulness to a failure to lack insufficient coffee

Comment: @romainl Nice one!  Hadn't even thought about using marks.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's an answer to the much more general question in the title: "How do I automatically re-load a file that gets modified by a bang (!) commandin Vim?" Some commands can't be invoked as filters.

Comment: "Some commands can't be invoked as filters." Then don't use them as filters.

Answer (score 0):

As the help for `:!` notes:

> Vim redraws the screen after the command is finished,
>               because it may have printed any text.  This requires a
>               hit-enter prompt, so that you can read any messages.
>               To avoid this use:
>
> ```
> :silent !{cmd}
> ```
>
> The screen is not redrawn then, thus you have to use
>               CTRL-L or ":redraw!" if the command did display
>               something.

So if you wanted to use the `:redraw!` approach, for example, you could do this using something like

```
nnoremap <leader>p :silent !js-beautify -r -j %<cr>:e!<cr>:redraw!<cr>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I still get the "Vim has changed on disk.  Do you want to reload?" prompt.